# Can you put code from .aws/config directly into your program?

Tags: amazon-s3, config, boto3, boto

I am using `boto3.client('s3')` to upload files with `s3.upload_file(filename, bucket, key, Callback=callback, Config=TransferConfig(use_threads=False))` and in my .aws/config file I have `s3 = max_concurrent_requests = 5`

Is there a way to get max_concurrent_requests hard coded into my program?

Comment: To what end? You can always hard code anything you want into your program.  Are you actually asking if its possible to retrieve a value from the config?

Comment: @Deadron I basically do not want to use the .aws/config file at all. However I can not figure out the proper way to put it in my code. If I put it in the `boto3.client("s3", max_concurrent_requests = 5) then it crashes my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation on the library there is the option to provide configuration from within your program.  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

An example from the docs

```
my_config = Config(
    region_name = 'us-west-2',
    signature_version = 'v4',
    retries = {
        'max_attempts': 10,
        'mode': 'standard'
    }
)

client = boto3.client('kinesis', config=my_config)
```

Answer (score 0):

`max_concurrent_requests` is only supported for the AWS CLI. You could shell out a command from a Python script to leverage this. Also, you can set it via the command line as well: `aws configure set s3 "max_concurrent_requests = 5"`. I haven't tested but I'd start there.

Here's a blog on how to execute shell commands from python: https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/

Comment: Side note: Did this lab at ReInvent last year: https://github.com/aws-samples/maximizing-storage-throughput-and-performance .. worth every second, I was pretty impressed  with the performance gains.